# deleting data in a domU-mounted image does not reduce the image size

Tags: filesystems, virtual-machine, disk-usage, xen, oracle-vm-server

I have difficulties understanding the following situation:

Dom0 image:

```
[root@Dom0]# du -h 19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
980M    19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
```

is mounted on DomU:

```
[root@DomU]# df -h /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde        50G   62M   47G   1% /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1
```

When I write data to `/u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1` the disk usage on DomU and Dom0 increases accordingly:

```
[root@DomU dbhome_1]# dd if=/dev/zero of=./test.img bs=4k iflag=fullblock,count_bytes > /dev/null
[root@DomU dbhome_1]# df -h /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde        50G   21G   27G  44% /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1
```

```
[root@Dom0]# du -h 19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
21G     19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
```

When I remove the data the diskusage of DomU is being reduced, but Dom0 stays the same:

```
[root@DomU dbhome_1]# rm test.img
[root@DomU dbhome_1]# df -h /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde        50G   62M   47G   1% /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1
```

```
[root@Dom0]# du -h 19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
21G     19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
```

How does the difference come about?

 

 
I did the following procedure to create and mount the image:

```
[root@Dom0]# qemu-img create 19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img.img 50G &>/dev/null
[root@Dom0]# xm block-attach domU file:19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img /dev/xvde w >/dev/null 2>&1
[root@Dom0]# ln -s 19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img.img /path/to/link/19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img
[root@Dom0]# vi vm.cfg (added link to disks[] parameter)
```

```
[root@DomU]# parted /dev/xvde mklabel gpt &>/dev/null
[root@DomU]# parted -s /dev/xvde mkpart primary 0 100% &>/dev/null
[root@DomU]# parted -s /dev/xvde set 1 lvm on &>/dev/null
[root@DomU]# echo "/dev/xvde /u01/app/oracle/product/19.12.0.0/dbhome_1 ext4 defaults 1 1\" >> /etc/fstab
[root@DomU]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvde &>/dev/null
[root@DomU]# mount -a &>/dev/null
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're wondering about! Is it that deleting data in a domU-mounted image does not reduce the image size?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, I updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert in XEN, but:

does one not need to tell `xm block-attach` that `discard`s in the domU can be passed through to the filesystem layer? Otherwise, "deleting files" in domU is not an operation that the image file "understands": All it sees is a few changes in a few positions, i.e. the changed directory and extent table entries. "Delete a file" is not something a block device has a notion of!

But: with the advent of SSDs came the `discard` operation, in which file systems, in this case, the file system driver of your domU, can tell the underlying storage device that a block of data is no longer needed. In that case, the SSD, or here, the hypervisor can use that information to actually remove that data from the file (and make it sparse again). So, you need support for that in:

1. the image file format and image block device driver in your dom0
2. the hypervisor (to be able to pass discards through to the image driver)
3. the domU file system and its mount options (to actually emit discards on data deletion)

Especially 3. is often not on by default: discard operations are often bundled/deferred. Try running `fstrim` on the domU filesystem!

However, it's rarely wise to immediately do that "sparsification" on the image driver for performance reasons, so there might be deferral / manual cleanup as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a misconception of how the blockdevice is handled by the filesystem. After some research I found that `resize2fs -fM 19.12.0.0_dbhome_1.img` on Dom0 updates the size of the image file.